# Should I destroy AlertDialog after closing it?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a simple AlertDialog in my code. It is called once user have entered invalid credentials and simply informs about that. User just clicks OK button and the dialog disappears. No additional actions are required.

```
var builder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.SetTitle(this.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.error))
  .SetMessage(this.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.wrongcredentials))
  .SetCancelable(false)
  .SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { builder.Dispose(); });
  builder.Create().Show();
```

Should I need to call a Dispose() method or builder = null or something to destroy AlertDialog by reason of allocating resources correctly?

Comment: not necessary but you can dismiss your dialog after completing your tasks like this dialog.dismiss(); (If you manually want otherwise gc can handle)

Comment: c#'s garbage collecter should do this for you... don't think there is a need to do so.